# sc-controller doesn't work in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, udev

I followed steps mentioned in post about making sc-controller works on ubuntu 20.04 ([How to get the sc-controller to function on 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233188/how-to-get-the-sc-controller-to-function-on-20-04)) but they didn't work for me.

1. I added `/dev/uinput rw,` to /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.sc-controller.sc-controller at line 30 (with two spaces in front to allign to the rest of the code)
2. I ran `sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.sc-controller.sc-controller`
3. I added: `KERNEL=="uinput", TAG+="snap_sc-controller"` to `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-snap.sc-controller.rules`
4. I ran `sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=misc`
5. After reboot when I ran `udevadm info /dev/uinput` I have `E: TAGS=:uaccess:seat:snap_sc-controller:`, but sc-controller is showing `Failed to create uinput device. Error code: -1`
   Anyone knows what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From step 3. please change `KERNEL=="uinput", TAG+="snap_sc-controller"` to `"KERNEL=="uinput", TAG+="snap_sc-controller_sc-controller"`

(missing another `sc-controller` at the end)

then redo step 4. to reload rules.