# sc-controller (Snap version) not detecting Steam Controller in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: snap

I cannot seem to get sc-controller (from Snap store) to detect my Steam Controller. I have the latest steam-devices drivers and tried the method described here ([How to get the sc-controller to function on 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233188/how-to-get-the-sc-controller-to-function-on-20-04)), but nothing is working. The program does start without any errors, it is simply not detecting my controller.

My Steam Controller does get recognized in Steam, but not on sc-controller. What can be done to resolve this?